# Space from line

Tags: memoir, line-spacing, microtype

How can i obtain the correct spacing of the two writings from the line? if you note the upper write is more far from the line...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}    
\RequirePackage[babel=true,tracking=true]{microtype}    
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}    
\newcommand{\ThinRule}{\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}}    
% Tracking (font spacing)    
\newcommand{\textlslarge}[1]{\textls[100]{#1}}    
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fontsize{22pt}{24.85pt}\selectfont
    \vfill
    \textsc{\textlslarge{Di \\ Isaac Newton}} \\
%    \vspace{-0.4cm}
    \ThinRule \\
    \textsc{\textlslarge{Londra, MMXII}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\rule`, so that it is drawn above the baselineskip:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}    
\RequirePackage[babel=true,tracking=true]{microtype}
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}    
\newcommand{\ThinRule}{\rule[0.5ex]{0.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}}    
% Tracking (font spacing)    
\newcommand{\textlslarge}[1]{\textls[100]{#1}}    
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fontsize{22pt}{24.85pt}\selectfont
    \textsc{\textlslarge{Di \\ Isaac Newton}} \\
    \ThinRule \\
    \textsc{\textlslarge{Londra, MMXII}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]